# Minus Percent Greater-Than vs Percent Greater-Than (i.e. -%> vs %>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am working my way through the tutorial posted here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/index.htm

One of the questions I have is that I see this used sparingly throughout the code samples:

```
<%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
```

Where other times, I see this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %>
```

Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a reason for that minus sign (-) before the closing `%>` or if its just a typo on behalf of the author.

On a side note, I've tried searching google and SO for similar questions, but `-%>` isn't exactly a google friendly search term.

Comment: Dang, that was quick.  I thought I'd try searching on Google again, and already this question is the first result for Ruby on Rails Minus Percent Greater Than : http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+on+rails+minus+percent+greater+than

Comment: +1 for using a google-friendly question header. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A dash either immediately after the opening tag (`<%-`) or immediately before the closing tag (`-%>`) trims all whitespace before or after the tag, respectively.  The most common use, such as you reference above, is to use `-%>` to avoid inserting a newline after the code.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and it was very easy to verify.  Thanks!